# Rails Seeding many 2 many table issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and having an issue seeding a many 2 many relationship table.  Here is the ERD 
[image: ERD Diagram]

I can successfully create users and projects with this:

```
user1 = User.create!({
  name: "Mike Rubin",
  userid: "merubin",
  password: "password",
  email:"mike@rubinsworld.com",
  avatar_url:"http://mike-rubin.com/images/nav/id/rubin_selfie_270.png"
})

project1 = user1.projects.create!({
name:"Mario's Match Game",
header1:"Javascript Project",
header2:"",
description:"Pre-work project for WDI-DC12 Bootcamp. Concentration like game where random cards are displayed and flipped as user choices. This work includes CSS, HTML5 along with Javascript and dynamic DOM manulipuation.
Bonus work to keep score and win and loss was done.",
screen_img_url:"http://mike-rubin.com/images/portfolio/mariomemorygame.jpg",
host_url:"http://www.rubinsworld.com/ga/memory/index.html"
})
```

If I try to create a portfolio with this:

```
portfolio1 = project1.portfolios.create!({
title:"Mike Rubin's Personal Portfolio",
description:"Welcome to Mike Rubin's Web Development Portfolio. "
})
```

I get this error:

```
$ rails db:seed
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist
```

Do I need to somehow create the ProjectsPortfio record first and seed the userid? if so how?
[schema and seeds located here on github](https://github.com/merubin/portfolio_management_system/tree/master/db)

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: could you add the models themselves to your question

Comment: If you want debugging advise you need to add a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question since none of us have a crystal ball that we can use to peer into your code.

Answer (score 0):

I woke up this morning to find I had left out a has_many :projects in the users model that was giving me the error.

I can now add the portfolio records.